# Laravel eloquent search query for two foreign tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a question about the code above , i want to search with criteria from 2 extra tables
I want 'charge' from charges table , 'name' from user table and also 'name' from customer table
all has binds the above query runs but the doesnt fetch data from customers->name any idea how to make it work?

```php
public function scopeSearch($query, $val){
    return $query->has('customer')
        ->whereHas('user', function($query) use ($val) {
            $query->where('tasks','like','%'.$val.'%')  
                ->Orwhere('name','like','%'.$val.'%');      
       })
       ->with('user')
       ->with('customer');
}
```

Comment: Do you have 'name' element in the protected $fillable array of Customer model ?

Comment: What do you mean by " but the doesnt fetch data from customers->name"? You mean, the `customer` relation in the result isn't filtered by `name`? Well, that's because the `whereHas()` is only applied to `charges`. `whereHas()` only checks if the subquery returns at least one result. You have to apply the same filter in `with()` by writing `with([ 'customer' => function($query) { … } ])`

Comment: I mean, as I understand from question, all the data is retrieving, but not the customer's name actually. Your version, and the Matias's answer is trivial, so I didn't think that this can be asked here:) As the person who already have written whereHas('user', *) function,then he also could do that for customers too. I just thinked that he might forgot to write that 'name' in the $fillable array (so therefore it's not retrieved from DB), that's why I didn't written that as an answer, cuz it simple. Anyway he also can do that via ->with('user.name'), but that's not about quaetion i think )

Comment: @boolfalse yes its on fillable arrays the 'name'

Comment: @boolfalse 
also i made that ->with('user.name') but i get error >Call to undefined relationship [name] on model [App\Models\User].

as i can see with matias answer the query runs but still have no customer->name on filtering, because i need a way to define the 'name' is from customers table and or the 'name' is from users table. i tried something ->Orwhere('customers.name','like','%'.$val.'%');  but still get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked! after some research i found that the problem was my using of or statement
the code above works for me:

```
  public function scopeSearch($query, $val){
    return $query->whereHas('user', function($query) use ($val) {
        $query->where('tasks','like','%'.$val.'%')
                ->orWhere('name','like','%'.$val.'%');
    })
        ->orWhereHas('customer', function($query) use ($val) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$val.'%');
        })
        ->with('user', 'customer');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) about adding stuff to your relation query (`whereHas`).

So, you should have this:

```php
public function scopeSearch($query, $val){
    return $query->with(['user', 'customer'])
        ->whereHas('user', function($query) use ($val) {
            $query->where('tasks','like','%'.$val.'%')  
                ->Orwhere('name','like','%'.$val.'%');      
       })
       ->whereHas('customer', function($query) use ($val) {
           $query->where('name','like','%'.$val.'%');
       });
}
```

See that you had only used `whereHas` for `users` but not `customers`...

Comment: Still cant filter customer->'name' 

The query that runs from debugbar is

select count(*) as aggregate from `charges` where exists (select * from `customers` where `charges`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id`) and exists (select * from `users` where `charges`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and (`tasks` like '%vas%' or `name` like '%vas%'))

it happends to have the same field 'name' for search  must define that the one 'name' is from users table and the other 'name' from customers,  on the query

Comment: That should not be happening as you are telling each query what to do. I am not sure then, sorry :(

Comment: Can you explain me please how that query knows which table to search? >Orwhere('name','like','%'.$val.'%')

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it takes into account the relation name, so it is going to use the relation query builder to do it (and it already has all the information it needs related to that relational table). If you see the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L136-L148) you will see it will call `getRelationWithoutConstraints`, that will do `$this->getModel()->{$relation}()`, that is the way of calling your relation builder (to get a new query related to it).